# Utilizing MySQL query results

Tags: mysql, powershell

Need help with solving this problem:
I need to get table data from MySQL DB for further use in script. I'm using this code for accessing MySQL data:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.7.4\Assemblies\v2.0\MySql.Data.dll")
$Connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$Connection.Open()
$Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($Query, $Connection)
$DataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Command)
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet,"data") | Out-Null
$Command.Dispose()
$Table=$DataSet.Tables["data"] | FT  -auto
$Connection.Close()
$Table
```

and it gives me my precious piece of junk:

```
TASKID TASKTYPE fistNAME secNAME STATUS
------ -------- -------- ------- ------
1111          1 Dep1                  0
2222          2 User321  Dep1         0
```

BUT when I try to, for example export results to CSV:

```
Export-Csv -Path "c:\test.csv" -InputObject $Table
```

all I get is:

```
#TYPE System.Object[]
"Count","Length","LongLength","Rank","SyncRoot","IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized"
"6","6","6","1","System.Object[]","False","True","False"
```

so when I try to parse data in variable like this:

```
Write-Host $Table
foreach ($Task in $Table) {
    Write-Host $Task.TASKID
}
```

all I get is:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

Can anyone help me to resove this problem?

Comment: What happens when you `write-host $Task` and then pipe it into a `format-list` and select all Properties? (`write-host $Task | fl -Property *`) That will show you all the Properties that you can access. You could also try `write-host $Task.TASKID.Value` that mite pull out the value of the `TASKID` property.

Comment: well on 'write-host $Task | fl -Property *' it gives me"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData" and on 'write-host $Task.TASKID.Value' another blank row

Comment: It's the way that your creating the variable `$Table` that is the problem. Have you tried the suggested answer below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line

```
$Table=$DataSet.Tables["data"] | FT  -auto
```

transforms your data into an array of `FormatStartData` objects.

Don't pipe your data into `Format-Table` when you want to export it. Try this instead:

```
$DataSet.Tables["data"] | Export-Csv "c:\test.csv"
```

Comment: YES this is the solution! you're the MAN.